# SQL to Entities with inheritance

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a simple inheritance in my model. The class of an entity is defined by a field (RecordType: int). Now I would like to create a SQL to Entities query where I need to filter only one inherited class.
When I use

```
ctx.CreateQuery<InheritedEntity>()
```

it fetches all the classes, rather than only InheritedEntity class.

I tried referring to the inherited class in the SQL:

```
"SELECT Value p FROM InheritedEntity as p"
```

But it doesn't work.

I tried adding

```
"... WHERE RecordType = ..."
```

But it doesn't work.

I couldn't find anything in MSDN either.

So how do I do that?

**EDIT:**

Eventually this code worked out for me:

```
 ctx.CreateQuery<BaseEntity>(sqlText).OfType<InheritedEntity>()
```

Now I'm wondering if this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ctx.CreateQuery<BaseEntity>(sqlText).OfType<InheritedEntity>()
```